# Setting common values for viewControllers in UITabBarController with moreNavigationController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have 'n' ViewControllers, all taking a common variable 'cv1', I would like to set this cv1 before the controllers are loaded. 
Everything is fine till I set only 4 controllers, (i.e) without More tab item. and once I introduce more controllers, delegate "tabBarController:didSelectViewController" doesn't trigger for the modules in UIMoreNavigationController.

So I tried setting the UINavigationController delegate for my TabBarController Class and handled the other module tabItem selection like

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    if navigationController != self.moreNavigationController
    {
        //navigation happening in some other tab Item
        return
    }

    if navigationController.viewControllers.count != 2
    {
        //The first controller of the more tabItem will be MoreViewController, followed by our desired controller in the navigation stack
        return
    }

    guard let selectedController:MyTabItemViewController = self.getTopViewController(from: viewController) else {

        print("***WARNING*** Selected controller doesn't seem to expect  info :\(String(describing: selectedViewController))")
        return

    }

    selectedController.sp = self.sp
    selectedController.sb = self.sb
}
```

I am able to get the ViewController instance, but the `viewDidLoad` method gets called before `UINavigationController`'s `willShow` method, I would like to set the variables before the `viewDidLoad` method as the UI structuring and data fetch depends on this variable.

Comment: don't you create these `n` controllers yourself? can't you just pass them the variable when you create them as a initializer's parameter?

Comment: I used storyboard to create the controllers, do you mean looping the UITabbarController's viewControllers Array and set the variables?

Comment: oh, storyboard.. I don't use storyboards, so I don't have much experience with that.. but maybe what you suggested would be a solution